# asp.net gridview master and detail data accessing from single cache enabled datasource

Tags: asp.net, caching, data-binding, gridview

Is there a way to get data for both the master rows and the detail rows in a single trip to the database and caching them properly ?

I want to be able to not have to connect to database when expanding any of the rows for the first time, so i would have to bind both master and detail to a single data source that has cache enabled. 
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, it is possible.  You can create a DataSet, fill it with the required data and save it to the cache.  Use the Page_Load event to obtain data from the cache and set the GridView's DataSource.  Please refer to the [Caching Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)